# jQuery - How to use one function which has "$(this)" as a selector, but $(this) has scope in second function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, this

How to call first function inside second function with "this" as a selector in the first function that is called in second function. Here is the code:

```
const _ERROR_MESSAGE = function(thisElement){ thisElement.after('<p class="error">'+thisElement.data("error-message")+'</p>') };

let _removeHtml = function(thisElement){ thisElement.next(".error").remove(); };

function validate(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $("form input[data-required]").each(function(index){
    if($(this).val().length <= 0){
      if($(this).next().hasClass("error") == false){
      _ERROR_MESSAGE($(this));
      }
    }
    else{
      _removeHtml($(this));
    }
  });
}
```

Is it possible to remove `$(this)` argument from function `_ERROR_MESSAGE($(this))` and `_removeHtml($(this))` and have it in their respective function definition and still work?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean, be able to use "this" as a literal in the method without an argument?

Comment: Yes @Taplar, can you please help with that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call  You can just use the call method.  `_ERROR_MESSAGE.call($(this));`

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that though.  Usually when you see a method using "this" for the context, you expect it to be a callback.  If you are not careful, using `call()` for this could lead to confusion in the future.

Comment: Yes, you can do what you want with the use of `call()`, as I already mentioned.

Comment: you should make `$(this)` into a variable instead of repeatedly calling it. you're making the script inefficient and slow by doing it.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar call() works just fine. But, now as you suggested to use callback, I tried doing it but, I gives me an error. I must me doing something wrong. Can you please help with that? I'll update the question.

Comment: I didn't suggest to use it as a callback.  I said that usually when "this" is used in a method, it is assumed that method is being used as a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the call method and "this" as a local variable in the first function for more efficient code.

```
var $_this = $(this);
```

In your own way:

```
const _ERROR_MESSAGE = function(){ this.after('<p class="error">'+this.data("error-message")+'</p>') };

let _removeHtml = function(){ this.next(".error").remove(); };

function validate(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $("form input[data-required]").each(function(index){
    var $_this = $(this);
    if($_this.val().length <= 0){
      if($_this.next().hasClass("error") == false){
      _ERROR_MESSAGE.call($_this);
      }
    }
    else{
      _removeHtml.call($_this);
    }
  });
}
```

If you want more efficient code and within the same function

```
function validate(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //Validate each form input
  $("form input[data-required]").each(function(index){
    var $_this = $(this);
    var $_error = $_this.next(".error");
    if($_this.val().length == 0) {
        if($_error.length == 0)
            $_this.after('<p class="error">'+$_this.data("error-message")+'</p>');
    } else
         $_error.remove();
  });
}
```